# Ошибка при попытке запуска примера XDevApi MySql Connector С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mysqlconnector

Всем добрый день! Пытаюсь запустить пример подключения к базе данных с [сайта](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/connecting-to-a-single-mysqld-node-setup.html)

Но мне выдается непонятное исключение и ничего не работает. Подскажите как с этим бороться?

Привожу пример кода и ниже приложу скрин ошибки:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>



#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
using namespace mysqlx;



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");

    string usr = "root";
    string pwd = "root";

    // Connect to MySQL Server on a network machine
  Session mySession(SessionOption::HOST, "localhost",
        SessionOption::PORT, 33060,
        SessionOption::USER, usr,
        SessionOption::PWD, pwd);



    Schema myDb = mySession.getSchema("crm");


    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если пройти дальше есть еще одно исключение его скриншот вот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приводите текстовую информацию текстом - вот я сижу с мобилы и что вы думаете я могу увидеть на подобном скрине? Я уже не говорю о том, что с текстом работать проще нежили с изображением (копирование, поиск и т.д.)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Добрый день! В том то и дело что там нечего приводить текстом. Пишет обнаружено необработанное исключение ... и все. Больше никакой информации.